# How do I express that a proposition is independent in TLA+?

Tags: tla+

Let's say the following is incorrect

```
THEOREM Spec => []P \* Not correct!
```

That is there is some behavior satisfying `Spec` that does not exhibit `[]P`. How can I express this in TLA+?

If I use simple negation, I end up with

```
THEOREM Spec /\ <>~P \* Also not correct!
```

However, it's possible that this theorem is also not correct! In particular, even though there is some behavior satisfying `Spec` that does not exhibit `[]P`, there is also possibly some behavior that does, and that behavior would disprove this new theorem.

Is there some way of expressing the idea "this theorem is incorrect for some behaviors," i.e. quantification over behaviors?

EDIT: After thinking a bit about the precise nature of what I'm asking for, I'm really asking is there a way of annotating `[]P` is independent of `Spec`?

Answer (score 0):

We are in classical logic, such that `[]P \/ ~[]P` is valid. You restated the second part, such that we have `[]P \/ <>~P`. So for any `P`, one of the two will be true.

Comment: Perhaps "incorrect" was too vague. What I aim to show or annotate is that this theorem is unprovable given a specification, not that a theorem is false.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this is to write `THEOREM ~(Spec => []P)`, make `[]P` a temporal property, and tell people that the spec is correct if the property *fails*.

Comment: But the property will not necessarily fail for every behavior (that negation is exactly equivalent to the conjunction I give in the second example). It will only fail for some. I'm asking to show or at least annotate that a given proposition is independent of the specification given.

Comment: So you want to say: there exists a behaviour for x such that  `<>~P(x)`? This is expressed with the first-order temporal operater `\EE x : <>~P(x)`. It is not easy to reason about it though.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x I was thinking about the temporal existential quantifier, but I don't think it gives me what I want without some contortions. `\EE` doesn't quantify over behaviors per se, it quantifies all values of `x` within a single behavior. If I bound every single variable in my module with `\EE` then that gives me my desired semantics in a round-about way; now every behavior does nothing and I've quantified all variables in a behavior to be a black-box sequence of values. Plus I have to define it in another module because I can't redefine my variables in the same module.

Comment: Is there a cleaner way of showing this? Or the statement (which I think is equivalent) that `[]P` is logically independent of `Spec`?

Comment: It might be a good idea to have a look at the actual spec together such that we can talk about specific behaviouts. Btw are you aware of the [tlaplus Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tlaplus/)? It's where all the developers of TLA+ read the messages.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the properties be parametrized as operators that take arguments, yes it is possible to express that there exists a behavior that satisfies `Spec(x)` but violates `[]P(x)`. Using existential temporal quantification (`\EE`), this is expressible as follows

```
Spec(x) == ...  (* a suitable definition here *)
P(x) == ...  (* a suitable definition here *)

THEOREM \EE x:  Spec(x) /\ ~ []P(x)
```

where we assume that no variables appear in the definitions of the operators `Spec(x)` and `P(x)`.

We could also express that there exist both a behavior that satisfies `Spec(x) /\ []P(x)`, and a behavior that satisfies `Spec(x) /\ ~ []P(x)`, as follows

```
THEOREM /\ \EE x:  Spec(x) /\ []P(x)
        /\ \EE x:  Spec(x) /\ ~ []P(x)
```